# How to copy from spawned expect process into file?

Tags: tcl, expect, qemu

I have a Raspberry Pi image running via a qemu emulator, which I interact with via expect.

I'm trying to capture the output from a particular command within the emulator, and save it to a file on the host.

Being a beginner with Tcl, I read through the manual and had a go at this. The "test.out" file is created but contains only a newline, while "Hello world!" appears on the console.

```
spawn qemu-system-arm --serial mon:stdio ...

expect {
    "login:" { send "pi\r" }
}
expect {
    "Password:" { send "raspberry\r" }
}
expect "pi@raspberrypi"

set ftty [exp_open -leaveopen]
set fsignature [open "test.out" w]

send "echo 'Hello world!'\r"
puts $fsignature [gets $ftty]
expect "pi@raspberrypi"

send "sudo shutdown now\r"
wait
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69300975/476716) was very useful in finding a solution.
However, for long outputs you need to account for the buffer filling up.

```
set fd [open "test.out" w]
send "cat large_output\r"
expect {
    -re {cat large_output[\r\n]+}  { log_user 0; exp_continue }
    -ex "\n" { puts -nonewline $fd $expect_out(buffer); exp_continue }
    -re $prompt { log_user 1; close $fd }
}
```

If the line length can exceed the buffer size then something more complicated is needed.

For some reason, the line endings are `\r\r\n`, but that can be fixed with a `sed`.

```sh
sed -i 's/\r//g' test.out
```

Comment: technically speaking this would not always work. when the beginning part of the prompt is captured with `full_buffer`, the remaining part of the prompt will not match `-re $prompt`. posted an answer. hope it can help.

Comment: @pynexj not sure why you deleted your answer, but I updated mine

Comment: mine was a too heavy weight. your update is good.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with `exp_open`. I would normally recommend something like this to capture command output:

```
set prompt {pi@raspberrypi}
set cmd {echo 'hello world'}
send "$cmd\r"
expect -re "$cmd\r\n(.*)\r\n$prompt"
puts $fsignature $expect_out(1,string)
```

Extracting command output can be tricky, because the sent command is (typically) displayed  and is included in the expect output. This assumes that your specified prompt appears first in its line.

Comment: Where is `exp_out` documented?

Comment: Oh, I spelled that wrong: `expect_out`. It's discussed in the `epxect [[-opts] pat1 body1 ...` command

Comment: This works in some cases, but not when the output length exceeds the expect buffer.

Comment: @OrangeDog you can use a loop to consume all the output until next prompt is displayed.

Comment: @sexpect-ExpectforShells can you add an answer showing that?